# Arduino beginner problems

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino

I'm very new to Arduino and experimenting with examples. I have a number of problems when using the following code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Telegraph.h"
//#include <Telegraph.h>

char* LETTERS[]  =  {
  ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".",      // A-E
  "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---",   // F-J
  "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---",      // K-O
  ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-",     // P-T
  "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--",  // U-Y
  "--.."                                 // Z
};

char* DIGITS[]  =  {
  "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--",     //0-3
  "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...",     //4-7
  "---..", "----."                        //8-9
};

Telegraph::Telegraph(const int outputPin, const int ditLength){
  _outputPin  =  outputPin;
  _ditLength  =  ditLength;
  _dahLength  =  dahLength;
  pinMode(_outputPin, OUTPUT);
}

void Telegraph::outputCode(const char* code){
  for(int i=0; i<strlen(code); i++){
    if( code[i]  ==  '.' )
      dit();
    else
      dah();
  }
}

void Telegraph::dit(){
  Serial.print(".");
  outputSymbol(_ditLength);
}

void Telegraph::dah(){
  Serial.print("-");
  outputSymbol(_dahLength);
}

void Telegraph::outputSymbol(const int length){
  digitalWrite(_outputPin, HIGH);
  delay(length);
  digitalWrite(_outputPin, LOW);
  delay(length);
}

void Telegraph::sendMessage(const char* message){
  for(int i=0;  i  <  strlen(message); i++){
    const char currentChar  =  toupper(message[i]);
    if( isalpha(currentChar) ){
      outputCode(LETTERS[currentChar  -  'A']);
      delay(_dahLength);
    }else if(isdigit(currentChar) ){
      outputCode(DIGITS[currentChar  -  '0']);
      delay(_dahLength);
    }else if(currentChar  =  ' '){
      Serial.print(" ");
      delay(_ditLength * 7);
    }
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Telegraph.cpp:6:15: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘LETTERS’
Telegraph.cpp: In constructor ‘Telegraph::Telegraph(int, int)’:
Telegraph.cpp:24:18: error: ‘dahLength’ was not declared in this scope
Telegraph.cpp: In member function ‘void Telegraph::sendMessage(const char*)’:
Telegraph.cpp:58:18: error: ‘LETTERS’ was not declared in this scope
Telegraph.cpp:63:30: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘currentChar’
```

Sorry if this question is too general but as I mentioned, I'm very new and don't entirely understand the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Telegraph.cpp:6:15: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘LETTERS’

Somewhere else the symbol `LETTERS` has been already defined. Perhaps in `Telegraph.h` ? You have to look for that.

```
Telegraph.cpp: In constructor ‘Telegraph::Telegraph(int, int)’:
Telegraph.cpp:24:18: error: ‘dahLength’ was not declared in this scope
```

The relevant code:

```
  _dahLength  =  dahLength;
```

Yes, `dahLength` is nowhere defined. Perhaps you wanted to add this as another parameter to the constructor?

```
Telegraph.cpp: In member function ‘void Telegraph::sendMessage(const char*)’:
Telegraph.cpp:58:18: error: ‘LETTERS’ was not declared in this scope
```

See above for that problem. Solve the first problem and ignore this one so long.

```
Telegraph.cpp:63:30: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘currentChar’
```

This is due to

```
}else if(currentChar  =  ' '){
```

where I'm sure you want to use `==` instead of `=`.